# where to put .properties files in an Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

I have a very simple properties file test I am trying to get working: (the following is TestProperties.java)

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class TestProperties {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResourceBundle myResources =
              ResourceBundle.getBundle("TestProperties");
        for (String s : myResources.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}
```

and TestProperties.properties in the same directory:

```
something=this is something
something.else=this is something else
```

which I have also saved as `TestProperties_en_US.properties`

When I run TestProperties.java from Eclipse, it can't find the properties file:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: 
Can't find bundle for base name TestProperties, locale en_US
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Put it at the root level of one of your source paths, or fully qualify the resource name in the call to `getBundle`, e.g.

```
ResourceBundle myResources =
          ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.test.TestProperties");
```

See the docs for [`ResourceBundle.getBundle(String, Locale, ClassLoader)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) for more information.

Answer (score 13):

Do NOT put your propierties files into your src folder! Obviously that works, but basically this is NOT how you should approach your problems. Create a new folder in your project, for instance a 'Resources' folder, add it to the classpath in project properties and put all files other than .java there.

Answer (score 2):

I have just been trying to solve this problem as well, I have found that you must refresh Eclipse's list of files  before you try to run your project. Then you can have your files in the base directory and use them as normal.

Answer (score 1):

put the TestProperties_en_US.properties(propery)  file in the src folder and then run  the program it will run

Answer (score 0):

Aha, thanks a bunch. This also works.

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class TestProperties {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResourceBundle myResources =
           ResourceBundle.getBundle(TestProperties.class.getCanonicalName());
        for (String s : myResources.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```